# Animated.css with a sticky navbar

Tags: html, css

Please help. That's my problem (see the screenshot below):

[image: Problem screenshot]

As you can see the navigation bar is underneath the image. This is my code:

```
<div class="navwrapper">
  <header class="nav">
    <nav>
      <div class="menu-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <img class="d-none d-md-block d-none" src="logo.png" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">FŐOLDAL</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">RÓLUNK</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">RENDELÉS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">KAPCSOLAT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="bg">
    <section style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle" class="sec1">
      <img class="animated bounceInDown" src="logo.png" alt="">
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a runnable [mcve] in the question itself and make sure it features the problem. Without it we can't tell you what is causing the issue or how to fix it.

Comment: At the very least, we'll need to see your CSS to have any shot at helping you out.